# Properly deleting a Deque of Pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, deque

I have a simple question. I have a deque,

```
std::deque<NPC*> enemyList
```

which contains dynamically allocated NPC objects. Each NPC object also has a pointer handle to a dynamically allocated Path and Shape object, which is accessible via the NPC class's getShape() and get Path() accessors.

This is how I am currently freeing the memory in this case:

```
while (enemyList.size() != 0) //delete npc's
{
    Shape3D *sPtr = enemyList.back()->getShape(); 
    Path *pPtr = enemyList.back()->getPath();
    NPC *npcPtr = enemyList.back();

    enemyList.pop_back();

    delete sPtr;
    delete pPtr;
    delete npcPtr;
}
```

This code compiles and seems to work fine, but I am unsure if it is technically correct.
Is this proper, and if not, what would be a better way of achieving the desired effect?

thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should work fine--as long as no exceptions are thrown. What you really want to use is a deque of [smart pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106508/what-is-a-smart-pointer-and-when-should-i-use-one) that will delete themselves whenever they go out of scope.

Or better yet, a [pointer-container](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_container.html), per boost.